# Adt bundle, eclipse segmentation fault, on linux

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to Android devt. so I've been trying to follow the instructions.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on an Asus 1201n laptop.

I have downloaded the adt bundle into my home directory and started eclipse.

I fixed the hyperlinks so they properly display the right help pages (really what kind of release is that?)

When I try to launch the virtual device manager, I get a segmentation fault...

Any ideas would be a great help.
Thanks,
Bob

```
~/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/eclipse$ ./eclipse 
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
(ADT:5792): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:454] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:455] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:455] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:455] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Do you use 32Bit or 64Bit? Does everything fit together?

Comment: It's a 32bit Ubuntu 12.04, fully up to date, running the XFCE window manager. What do you mean by "fit together"?  Eclipse starts up ok, but then crashes after a few interactions, in particular when I try to access the virtual device maanager... Thanks for your help!

Comment: With "fit together" I meant: OS, JDK, Eclipse and ADK is all 32Bit.

Comment: Ah, sorry for not understanding. Yes, everything is coherently 32bit...